# PyCharmでPEP8違反をnoinspectionで抑止したい

Tags: python

PEP8に違反している箇所、具体的には1行の文字数超過をしている部分に、
 # noinspection PyPep8
をつけても警告が解除できないのはなぜでしょう?

PreferencesのInspectionの方で解除することはなるべくやりたくありません。
PEP8違反に対して、その部分だけ警告解除する手段はないのでしょうか?

Comment: その仕様を知りませんでした。Helpでも見つけられませんでしたが、情報現はどこでしょう？

Comment: 本家StackOverFlowのいくつかの質問に出てきたので、検索して
http://blog.codeoptimism.com/pycharm-suppress-inspections-list/
を見つけました。

PyPep8 がどうにもならないので調べてくれる人がいないかなぁ、と思いまして。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ヘルプでの説明](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/suppressing-inspections.html#1)に従ってみたけど、1行の文字数超過をしている場合では例の説明は働きませんでした。

でも、以下のように  `# noqa`を行末に入力すれば、警告解除できるようです。Pep8の違反警告のために外部ツールを使って、`.py`ファイルの全体を確認しているので、pycharmの`# noinspection`が働かないと思います。

> `long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_long_line_ = 8  # noqa`

[How to disable a pep8 error in a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444840/how-to-disable-a-pep8-error-in-a-specific-file)というSO質問をご参照下さい。

Comment: リンク先を読んでみて、 # noqa あるいは # nopep8 で警告が抑止できることが確認できました。
有用な情報ありがとうございました。